# Extract text and nodes from <p> using lxml in the same array index

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

Hello i need get all text and other things inside a pharagrap something like this:

```
<div>
<p>
Whatever you want type <strong>here is great</strong>
</p>
<p>
Whatever you want type <strong>here is great</strong>
</p>
</div>
```

I am using this to get all text and strong text from the pharagraps but the problem is that using this way the text and strong text is processed by split, then i get an array like this ['Whatever you want type','here is great'] and i need get the nodes in the same array index, something like this ['Whatever you want type here is great']

```
content = html.xpath('.//p/text() | .//p/strong/text()')
```

I found a way to extrac the text inside them:

> .text_content(): Returns the text content of the element, including
> the text content of its children, with no markup.

https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Comment: Try `content = html.xpath('string(//p)')`

Comment: nah doesn't work

Comment: did you try using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) ?

Comment: I need use xpath/lxml

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I mean that it works, exaclty i can take the strong label also, but it doesn't work because using string i only can take the first p node

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = """<p>
 Whatever you want type <strong>here is great</strong>
</p>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')
mytext = [soup.find('p').get_text().strip()]
#['Whatever you want type here is great']
```

Comment: I want use lxml/xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I tested it in scrapy

```
import scrapy
html="""<p>
Whatever you want type <strong>here is great</strong>
</p>"""
data = scrapy.Selector(text=html)

data.xpath("//p//text()[1]").getall()
```

output

> ['\nWhatever you want type ', 'here is great']